# How to get Rails engine version from an application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have developed a Rails engine which I'm mounting in an application.

In development environment I can retrieve the engine version with `MyEngine::VERSION` (which is living in /lib/my_engine/version.rb).

This gives an error (uninitialized constant MyEngine::VERSION) in staging, and I imagine it would fail in production as well.

How could I fix this?

Comment: just curious, try `::MyEngine::VERSION` does that work?

Comment: @derekyau nope, although I try to get it that way the error is exactly the same: uninitialized constant MyEngine::VERSION

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding:

```
require 'my_engine'
```

and/or

```
require 'my_engine/version'
```

To the top of the file.  Rails does some confusingly inconsistent things with when it chooses to automatically require code and when it doesn't; I'm guesing it might differ between development and production, from your description that it works in development environment but not another environment.

`error (constant not found)` sounds like it means `MyEngine` is not actually loaded yet, and the solution to that is to `require` it at the top of the file, to make sure it gets loaded if it wasn't already. Standard ruby is really always to `require` anything you use at the top of any file that uses it; Rails tries to let you get away without doing this in some cases, but it can be confusing to understand what those cases are exactly, and they don't always seem to work consistently. So just `require`, it won't hurt.

Comment: Thanks. Using the second require was just fine.

Comment: Cool. You also might want to add the `require 'my_engine/version'` to the top of `my_engine.rb` -- that way whenever anyone loads MyEngine, it'll automatically make sure to load MyEngine::VERSION too, instead of requiring the calling code to require it separately. That's a common practice in engine code, and one that some engine template generators do for you.

Comment: Do you mean the lib/my_engine.rb file? It was already, but not on top. Rails automatically added it below 'coffee-rails', 'sass-rails' and the rest.

Comment: I did mean the `lib/my_engine.rb` file, but now I'm confused as to what's going on, so maybe I'll just leave it at that. I would not expect to see anything relating to coffee-rails or sass-rails in that file.

Comment: Oh yes sorry, that's me who added that for loading dependencies from the gemspec file. Do you think it would make a difference moving the version require to the top?

Comment: Not really sure to be honest -- it depends on what's going on. You can reason through it yourself. The key is that after "require my_engine/version" gets called, that's when MyEngine::VERSION will be available. You want to make sure it gets called before something else tries to access MyEngine::VERSION. It's a bit of a mystery why it wasn't working right before -- unless something in the middle of the file tried to access MyEngine::VERSION (or required somethign which requied something which tried too...) before your require came at the end of the file.